# How to programmatically create border for cells of a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid" Visibility="Visible" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="600" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" />
                <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1" />
</Grid>
```

In this XAML code I am putting a border in two cells of a grid. I need to change the design and do the same thing in C# instead. I know how to instantiate a Border in C# and assign it properties, but how do I associate each Border object with the correct cell in the Grid? (named here 'LayoutGrid' ). In other words how do I do in C# what the  element is doing in the XAML code above?

Comment: why would you like to do that? if it depends on some condition, you might like to create the border in a style or with binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `myBorder` is already child of `LayoutGrid`

```
var myBorder = new Border();
LayoutGrid.Children.Add(myBorder)
```

you either use `Grid` static methods

```
Grid.SetColumn(myBorder, 0);
Grid.SetRow(myBorder, 1);
```

or set `DependencyProperty` it directly

```
myBorder.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
myBorder.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a Brush:

```
Border brdr = new Border() 
{ 
    BorderThickness = new Thickness() 
    { 
        Bottom = 1, 
        Left = 1, 
        Right = 1, 
        Top = 1 
    }, 
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) 
};
```

Then the code listed above will work.